# Magento multi-country/multi-domain set up

Tags: magento, nginx, multiple-domains

Here is the scenario:

-I have a friend who owns a magento site, for example abcd.co.uk.
-They would like to expand their business to some other European countries, so they have purchased abcd.at, abcd.be, abcd.de etc domains
- They want to use the same catalogue, same interface, same everything available on all those domains except, the currency (which is going to be the automatic rate conversion), store addresses, help contact addresses etc.
-There are no language translation requirements. Everything will be in English

After reading a plethora of forums and help manuals, this is what we did:
-created, 1 website, 1 store and 1 store view, for each of those domains.
-configured their urls and currencies at website level.
-created a folder called stores within the main magento installation and created individual folders for each of those domains, inside that folder.
-copied index.php and .htaccess files to each of those and configured them (to realise later that .htaccess file configuration was in vain as the vps is using nginx).

Question 01. Is this the correct approach for what we need? Or have we missed something or followed any unnecessary steps?
Question 02: IF it is the correct approach, could some explain, step by step how to complete the rest of the steps (virtual host configuration using nginx and any other necessary steps, please?

As I’ve mentioned, I did my homework and found plenty of information about how to set up Apache but very patchy information about nginx set up. To make it worse, I know nothing about nginx

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally I would do it without subfolder ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315580/magento-multistore-subfolder-without-symlinks/13316186#13316186 .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312491/htacces-setenvif-to-nginx-fastcgi-param-conversion ... http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento

Comment: @R.S - thanks mate. I really like that option (without sub folders) but I have a couple of questions. To which configuration file I should add that "if ($host = mywebsite1.com) {}"? Is it to main nginx.conf file or the mymainwebsite.conf file? If it is to the main nginx.conf file, do I still have to create individual mywebsite1.conf files for every additional domain? Many thanks.

Comment: I just start using nginx (so little experience).. but since it is in 'if statement' I would put it in the individual config so you can easily add and delete site

Comment: @R.S. If we create individual conf files, according to [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento), I don't see a reason to use if statement in those files. I had a look around and found [this](http://www.coeusblue.com/blog/48-magento/68-nginxmagentomultisite). It looks like even cleaner approach. Going to give it a go and will update the results soon. Thank you so much for directing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar task once.
What I did was:

1. Single magento folder, single index.php.
2. Magento has multiple websites/stores/store views with proper URL domain, currency, root category settings.
3. index.php file is configured to run the store_view depending on the domain.

So how to do this 'dispatching'? It is described [here](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/#parked-domain-method).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just one question though. Do I have to make changes to index.php file at all? If I'm not wrong, according to this [http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup), anything above 1.4 doesn't need those index.php file changes.

Comment: Sure you should! I'v provided a link in 'here' word. How to to it properly.

Comment: Tried that solution last night and everything worked like a charm :-) Thanks all for directing me to the right direction.