# How to properly use Git. Using CodeIgniter w/ DEVELOPMENT, TESTING, and PRODUCTION servers

Tags: php, git, codeigniter

Basically, I have a file `index.php` which should be different in each server. The file indicates which server it is on.

*It has something like this:*

On the **DEVELOPMENT** environment:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

On the **TESTING** environment:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'testing');
```

On the **PRODUCTION** environment:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'production');
```

What's the proper way to maintain these files on each server without Git touching it?

I've added the file to `.gitignore` now, and I've untracked it using `git rm --cached index.php` then `git push origin master` for TESTING server and `stable` for PRODUCTION server.

Comment: You have done what's necessary to keep these files out of reach of Git, now what issue are you facing

Comment: @Rahul I'm afraid that if I pull from my development repo to my testing server, the testing server will delete the index.php file. Will it delete the file? Because I don't want it to. I just wanted to stop tracking it.

Comment: Well I don't think that it will delete your index.php on testing server if it is untracked

Comment: @Rahul here's the error I'm having now trying to PULL to my TESTING server: http://imgur.com/a/NSuto

Comment: I cannot see the image, as the access is denied could you upload to somewhere else

Comment: do you use apache ?

Comment: @Rahul ok i just made the image public on Imgur. or is it Imgur you can't go on? http://imgur.com/a/NSuto

Comment: @sintakonte i use apache for development server and apache&nginx for testing and production server.

Comment: It is imgur I cant access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fyi,

if you use apache you don't really have to change the index.php file because you can use your htaccess file to define your environment

for example :

```
SetEnvIf Host yourdevdomain$ CI_ENV=development
SetEnvIf Host yourtestdomain$ CI_ENV=testing
SetEnvIf Host example.com$ CI_ENV=production
```

In this case, you can set your needed Environments in your htaccess file, and you don't have to worry about overwriting some stuff with different files from different environments.

> i think there is an option on nginx too
>
> Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312491/htacces-setenvif-to-nginx-fastcgi-param-conversion)

You can get more information from the official CI Documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html?highlight=environment).

Comment: Oh geez. If only I knew earlier... So if I do make such changes to the .htaccess file, what do I do with the index.php?

Comment: Oh, I can just leave it as is? Since it only changes the ENVIRONMENT constant IF it isn't already set, right?

Comment: and thus, i can retrack the index.php, correct? (by removing it from the .gitignore file)

Comment: i'm not an GIT expert, but i think so

Comment: One potential problem with this very good answer is that the Apache server might not have the `mod_env` module enabled. If that is true then the `CI_ENV` value will not be passed to scripts. I have run into this on some shared hosting environments.

Comment: Okay, for some reason it isn't working... I have this set up in my htaccess:

`SetEnvIf Host developmentserver$ CI_ENV=development`
`SetEnvIf Host testing.mydomain.com$ CI_ENV=testing`
`SetEnvIf Host www.mydomain.com$ CI_ENV=production`

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @DFriend how do I enable mod_env?

Comment: @DFriend nvm i just went into my httpd-vhosts.conf file and changed it from `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 0):

With Apache you can set CI_ENV like @sintakonte's answer. With nginx and php-fpm you can set CI_ENV like this:

```
location ~ \.php {
    ....
    fastcgi_param CI_ENV production;
}
```

And leave the index.php file as default.

Cheers.